# How can I print information about your Java project

Tags: java, maven

Is there a command line tool or a maven plugin to easily print out information about your project?

For example

- give me all the classes and methods with `@Test` annotations.
- give me all the classes with `@Ignore` annotations.
- list all methods in class

etc..

Currently, I keep writing maven plugins that load classes and iterate over them, but I would like to find some tool to do the job for me.

Comment: Listing all methods in a class like a javadoc?

Comment: @Compass - something like it.. but from a command line. to use it with scripts.

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html Potentially with a custom javadoc generator that basically only provides you the above categories

Answer (score 0):

Think about using jQAssistant - it scans artifacts and puts the results into a Neo4j database. Then you can query the database for the things you mentioned (and much more).